# sceneKit SCNIKConstraints Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am using SceneKit for a robot arm control project; have some issues with Inverse Kinematics, code crashes at the top of the delegate file upon invoking the IK call:

```
  let myIKConstraint = SCNIKConstraint(chainRootNode: scene.myJoint1!)
  self.scene.eLSJ3?.constraints = [myIKConstraint]
  let myTarget: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(20, 50, 200)
  myIKConstraint.targetPosition = myTarget
```

System crashes with a Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS message! 
Have tried enabling zombies, did not shed any light on the issue??? any clues???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: let myIKConstraint = SCNIKConstraint(chainRootNode: scene.myJoint1!)
      self.scene.eLSJ3?.constraints = [myIKConstraint]
      let myTarget: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(20, 50, 200)
      myIKConstraint.targetPosition = myTarget

Comment: Not sure why, but if you change `SCNIKConstraint(chainRootNode)` to `SCNIKConstraint.inverseKinematicsConstraint(chainRootNode:)`, then it works. Filed a bug: https://openradar.appspot.com/47774257

Comment: Oh, I see now that that's what you meant when you said "using the static function." Going to leave this here in case others find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the static function equivalent instead of instantiating the SCNIKConstraint class?

I still do not comprehend why the above code crashed the app? 
On a different note: Thank you Hal Mueller for formating my code above.. :-)